# Google Sheets function equivalent to Excel's Goal Seek function?

Tags: google-sheets

In Excel, there's a function called **Goal Seek** that will change an input value in one cell such that an output value in another cell hits a certain value.  A summary of the function can be found [here](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/goal-seek.html).

Is there a way to do the same in Google Sheets?  It doesn't seem to be a native feature, so happy to use an add-on or some other method.

Comment: most likely doable in various ways. depends on the input. pls share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Google has recently added a Goal Seek add-on. See the Google Help Article "Find an unknown value with Goal Seek" at https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9506732
or do a search on "**Google Sheets Goal Seek**" for more information.

Comment: Prior to "Google Sheets Goal Seek" there was another (third party) version the actually worked. The new version gives up after a few seconds without reaching the goal. It also alters cell values and cell formatting. It's pretty rubbish.